# is there a way to auto generate ObjectId when a mongoose Model is new'ed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

is there a way to declare a Model schema in mongoose so that when the model is new'ed the _id field would auto-generate?

for example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectIdSchema = Schema.ObjectId;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    _id:            ObjectIdSchema,
    firstName:      {type: String, default: 'N/A'},
    lastName:       {type: String, default: 'N/A'},
    age:            {type: Number, min: 1}
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

at first, i thought great!, i'll just do

```
_id:    {type:ObjectIdSchema, default: new ObjectId()}
```

but of course that doesn't work, because new ObjectId() is only called on initialize of schema. so calling new Persion() twice creates two objects with the same _id value.

so is there a way to do it so that every time i do "new Person()" that a new ObjectId() is generated?

the reason why i'm trying to do this is because i need to know the value of the new person's _id value for further processing.

i also tried:

```
var person = new Person({firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Baz"});
person.save(function(err, doc, num){
    console.log(doc._id);
});
```

even then, doc doesn't contain the ObjectId. but if i look in the database, it does contain it.

p.s. i'm using mongoose 2.7.1

p.p.s. i know i can manually create the ObjectId when creating the person as such:

```
var person = new Person({_id: new ObjectId(), firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Baz"});
```

but i rather not have to import ObjectId and have to new it every time i want to new a Person. guess i'm used to using the java driver for mongodb, where i can just create the value for the _id field in the Model constructor.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the moment you call var person = new Person();
person._id should give you the id (even if it hasn't been saved yet). Just instantiating it is enough to give it an id. You can still save it after, and that will store the id as well as the rest of the person object

Comment: Yep, and no need to include the `_id` field in the schema.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, you and Last Rose Studios are correct. it's exactly as you said. i commented out the line "_id: ObjectIdSchema," and when i new'ed Person() it had the id! but when i didn't comment it out, the id was never generated. thanks guys! much appreciated.

Comment: For new viewers, has this behaviour changed since? Today I was forced to mention `default: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` without which it wasn't working if I added `_id` inside the model schema!

Comment: I can echo the above comments, using node version 4.8.1 , if _id is declared in Schema , the _id won't be auto generated

Answer (score 35):

Add the `auto` flag:

```
_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    index: true,
    required: true,
    auto: true,
  }
```

[source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1285)

Comment: No need to explicitly specify an `_id`: `In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique _id field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field.`. [Read the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

Comment: That will fail if my TypeScript type for `_id` field is `string` causing invalid casting to `typeof Mixed | StringConstructor | typeof String`

Answer (score 17):

Instead of:

```
_id:    {type:ObjectIdSchema, default: new ObjectId()}
```

You should do:

```
_id:    {type:ObjectIdSchema, default: function () { return new ObjectId()} }
```

Comment: This is unnecessary... If you don't specify what an _id is, it defaults to ObjectId and creates itself

Comment: [Error: document must have an _id before saving]

Comment: This answer is still useful, since subdocuments, for example, don't have auto-generated _id

Comment: this is still actual, especially to dockerized mongo image

Answer (score 10):

Taken from the official MongoDB Manual and Docs:

### _id

> A field required in every MongoDB document. The `_id` field must have a
>   unique value. You can think of the `_id` field as the document’s primary
>   key. If you create a new document without an `_id` field, MongoDB
>   automatically creates the field and assigns a unique BSON ObjectId.
>   
>   [Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-id)

---

### ObjectID

> ObjectIds are small, likely unique, fast to generate, and ordered.
>   *ObjectId* values consist of 12 bytes, where the first four bytes are a
>   timestamp that reflect the ObjectId’s creation. Specifically:
>
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch, a 5-byte
>   random value, and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value. In
>   MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique `_id`
>   field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the
>   `_id` field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an *ObjectId*
>   for the `_id` field.
>
> This also applies to documents inserted through update operations with
>   upsert: true.
>
> MongoDB clients should add an `_id` field with a unique *ObjectId*.
>   Using ObjectIds for the `_id` field provides the following additional
>   benefits: in the mongo shell, you can access the creation time of the
>   *ObjectId*, using the `ObjectId.getTimestamp()` method. sorting on an _id
>   field that stores ObjectId values is roughly equivalent to sorting by
>   creation time. 
>  **IMPORTANT**
>  While *ObjectId* values should increase over
>   time, they are not necessarily monotonic. This is because they:
>
> Only contain one second of temporal resolution, so *ObjectId* values
>   created within the same second do not have a guaranteed ordering, and
>   Are generated by clients, which may have differing system clocks.
>   
>   [Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

#### Explicitly declaring `_id`:

When explicitly declaring the `_id` field, specify the `auto` option:

```js
new Schema({ _id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true }})
```

> ObjectId only - Adds an auto-generated ObjectId default if turnOn is true.
>   [Source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1285#issuecomment-13419165)

---

### TL;DR

If you create a new document without an _id field, MongoDB automatically creates the field and assigns a unique BSON ObjectId.

Comment: This is the exact answer, and the only thing that worked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is good way to do this

in model:

```
const schema = new Schema({ userCurrencyId:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        index: true,
        required: true,
        auto: true});
```