# Cast error while executing a mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am executing a query in mongoose where I need to find all the users in my database and sort them and limit the results to 10.
My query route is:**(the route is "/user/top")**

```
router.get('/top', middleware.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
User.find({}).sort({bestScore: 1}).limit(10).exec(function (err, result) {
    if(err){
        res.json({
            status:"error",
            data:err
        });
    }
    else {
        res.json({
            status:"ok",
            data: result
        })
    }
})
});
```

My User model:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
image: String,
displayName: String,
bestScore:Number,
});
```

The error while i call the url from postman
[image: Erro Image]

**EDIT 1:**

Output of mongodb query:
[image: Output of my query]

You can see that my _id is of type ObjectId .

Comment: you probably have documents stored in the collection where the _id is not an ObjectId

Comment: But when i am running the same command in my terminal it is getting executed.

Comment: the shell doesn't care what type the `_id` is, mongoose does - because of your schema - since it is not explicitly declared it is assumed to be of type ObjectId.

Comment: Is there something else which i can do ? I want mongoose to save it as ObjectId .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set \_id to db document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose)

Comment: I want it to save as ObjectId only and it is getting saved like that only when I am creating a user(which is done automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Your data probably contains a document which looks like this:

```
{
    _id: "top",
    ...
}
```

Since Mongoose expects that value to be an ObjectId by default you get this error. What you can do is map the `_id` field explicitly as a `string`:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    image: String,
    displayName: String,
    bestScore:Number,
});
```

Comment: _id is the field which mongoose generates by default when an entry is created

Comment: Yes but it would generate an ObjectId not a string value which your data appears to contain.

Comment: Is there something else which i can do ? I want mongoose to save it as ObjectId .

Comment: Yes, but you would need to change your existing data to make Mongoose understand it without a changed mapping. And when you save your document - that code is missing from your question - you should make sure not to save "top" or anything as the "_id" value but a valid ObjectId instead.

Comment: I am not saving like that . the _id gets automatically assigned by mongoose

Comment: I have no idea how your are saving your data but something's clearly not correct: Mongoose will autogenerate an ObjectId for you not a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604928/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-objectid-when-a-mongoose-model-is-newed

Comment: I am saving it as answered in the question. I have not declared _id in my schema and therefore mongoose generates the _id automatically

Comment: Can you please post the output of your MongoDB console query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162573/discussion-between-user8885733-and-dnickless).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you had is that your search route is going through findbyId. if you truly wanna search/find all users without using an Id, you need to make sure in your controller, your search comes before your getbyId. same also in your route. I had the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304207/how-to-query-using-a-specific-field-instead-of-id-in-express-js/53427625#53427625) and I was able to solve it from my route by putting my search function before getbyId.

Also, when you are using postman, kindly enter the search parameter as seen in my own case study below;
take note the path and my parameter key and value:[image]