# how to query using a specific field instead of id in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

Below is my code to query search by city. I am getting not found in my post> I need to be able to search for a specific city and get all the records for the field that matches the city. For example, if city is Downtown, I want all the records with the city downtown

```
            router.get("/search", (req, res, next) =>{
            const city = req.query.city;
            Facility.findAll(city)
                .select('name type mobile price streetName city state _id')
                .exec()
                .then(docs => {
                console.log("From database", docs);
                if (docs) {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        facility: docs
                    });
                } else {
                    res
                    .status(404)
                    .json({ message: "No valid entry found for provided City" });
                }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({ error: err });
                });

            });
```

Comment: do you need to add _id to the select feed? just curious 

Comment: Please state the error you're getting as well

Comment: message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" at path "_id" for model "Facility"',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working code:

```
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
const city = req.query.city
    Facility.find({city})
        .select('name type mobile price streetName city state')
            .exec((err, docs) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500)
                    .json({ message: 'error querying cities', error: err });
                }
                if (!docs) {
                    return res.status(404)
                    .json({ message: 'No valid entry found for provided City' });
                }
                return res.status(200)
                    .json({
                    count: docs.length,
                    facility: docs
                });
            })
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to do it;

```
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  const {city} = req.query
  Facility.find({city})
    .select('name type mobile price streetName city state')
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500)
          .json({ message: 'error querying cities', error: err });
      }
      if (!docs) {
        return res.status(404)
          .json({ message: 'No valid entry found for provided City' });
      }
      return res.status(200)
        .json({
          facility: docs
        });
    })
})
```

`find()` will do the job. I don't see a need for you to select `_id`, you only specify with `-_id` if you don't want it but `_id` is selected by default.

Below is a list of valid queries in Mongoose if that is what you're using

```
Model.deleteMany()
Model.deleteOne()
Model.find()
Model.findById()
Model.findByIdAndDelete()
Model.findByIdAndRemove()
Model.findByIdAndUpdate()
Model.findOne()
Model.findOneAndDelete()
Model.findOneAndRemove()
Model.findOneAndUpdate()
Model.replaceOne()
Model.updateMany()
Model.updateOne()
```

Check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html for more information on queries

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just specify your query and you should be fine

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

```
router.get("/search", (req, res, next) =>{
        const city = req.query.city;
        Facility.findAll({propertyName: city})
            .select('name type mobile price streetName city state _id')
            .exec()
            .then(docs => {
            console.log("From database", docs);
            if (docs) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    facility: docs
                });
            } else {
                res
                .status(404)
                .json({ message: "No valid entry found for provided City" });
            }
            })
            .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
            });

        });
```

Comment: it didn't work when I used postman. See error below 

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"search\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Facility\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"search\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "search",
        "path": "_id"
    }
}

below is the link i used:   http://localhost:9944/facilities/search?Sabo

Comment: It's still trying to query _id property. can you update your code?