# Does Mongoose automatically create unique IDs for me when I do a save?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have simple code I use as follows:

```
// mongoose helper methods
const saveInstance = (name, schema, obj) => {
  const Model = mongoose.model(name, schema);
  const Instance = new Model(obj);
  return Instance.save();  
};
```

The schema does not have an ID property yet I see this in the database:

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "5c14201afbf31900047f9ccf"
    },
```

I want to assume that Mongoose is creating this ID or is it MongoDB that creates this?  Can you provide a reference?

Also, why the strange syntax of an object in an object, why not just put the ID directly as value of `_id`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way to auto generate ObjectId when a mongoose Model is new'ed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604928/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-objectid-when-a-mongoose-model-is-newed) It's exactly what you're looking for & check answer from `user0800` for more details..

Comment: Yes most are incorrect & people have commented stating the same, that's why I've mentioned to read answer from `user0800` which is correct/latest & it does provide most information to multiple questions you're asking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB blog post:

> By default, MongoDB generates a unique ObjectID identifier that is assigned to the _id field in a new document before writing that document to the database.

[post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks.  Perfect answer.  Can you provide an official reference from MongoDB?  Not a blog entry.

Comment: yes, read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid
Could you mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 questions, let me address each of them.

1. > Mongoose is creating this ID or is it MongoDB that creates this?

The more accurate answer would be the **MongoDB Node.js driver** (not the MongoDB server)

Let's make a clear distinction about what we are referring to:

- [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) = The Node.js **library** that wraps around the [official MongoDB Node.js driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)
- [MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) (driver) = The database **client** library that connects to a [MongoDB Server](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)
- [MongoDB Server](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) = The database **server** that stores your data, available in 2 editions: [Community](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) & [Enterprise](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise)

Please note from the [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

> MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field

...

> MongoDB clients should add an _id field with a unique ObjectId.

The `_id` field is generated at the **client** side, unlike some databases that have the functionality to generate the primary field at the database server.

What actually happens is that Mongoose calls the `ObjectId` function that is provided by the MongoDB native driver. This is done without the server, i.e. you can generate an `ObjectId` without a server connection. You can try the following code:

```
/* no any database connection logic */
const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema() // blank schema, should contain only _id field

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema)
const test = new Test()

console.log(test.toString()) // this will log an object with an _id field
```

[See output on RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/fcfwn239a57w)

2. > Also, why the strange syntax of an object in an object, why not just put the ID directly as value of `_id`?

This is just a string representation of the actual 96-bit data. It's an [Extended JSON](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst) format that is used to represent MongoDB documents as human readable.